# Substituir dados no RStudio

Tags: banco-de-dados

Sou novo na programação em R e estou com um problema. Eu possuo duas colunas (X e Y, respectivamente), na primeira eu possuo uma série de valores, onde alguns são negativos e eu preciso de uma função que para cada valor negativo em X, substitua o valor em Y por 0.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo para ficar mais claro.

```
p <- rnorm(10000)
p[p<0] <- 0
```

Uma função:

```
trocaNegativo <- function(x) { x[x<0] <- 0; x }
trocaNegativo(p)
```

No seu slice, você pode colocar uma clausula e filtrar o que vc quer por nesse slice.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.